# Админ панель для создания/редактирования/удаления товаров PHP,SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Имеется БД, в которой 3 таблицы:

- Товары,
- Бренды ( которые подключены к категориям)
- Собственно, категории.

Нужно написать что-то вроде админ панели, где простой пользователь не заходя на phpmyadmin, может добавлять редактировать и удалять все вышеперечисленное.

Ни в коем случае не прошу вас сделать это за меня, но прошу подсказать где можно посмотреть что-то наподобие этого и написать для меня, либо есть ли готовый продукт который я смогу подключить к моему коду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы подошли к теме `CRUD` - **Create Read Update Delete**. Чтобы вам работать эффективно нужно будет пользоваться готовыми библиотеками, которые будут предоставлять вам готовый функционал для работы с БД, а так же реляции(ваши категории). Можете начать с [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php).

Также можете начать изучать какой-нибудь фреймворк, к примеру [Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/).

Comment: Серия Yii мертва чуть больше чем полностью

Comment: Они готовят Yii3, релиз будет в 2019, самое то научиться человек и освоиться на паттерны MVC и как устроен ORM.

Comment: Готовить можно все, что угодно, но когда от вас уходит автор, это обо многом говорит

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [LiteCart](https://www.litecart.net/ru/), возможно оно вас устроит. У них есть демо [магазина](http://demo.litecart.net/) и [админки](http://demo.litecart.net/admin/).

Посмотрите ещё в сторону [SBAdmin](https://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/)

Comment: Я как понял, его интегрировать к моему сайту составит несколько проблем. Мне бы что-то чтобы подключить уже к готовому проекту.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону https://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/

Comment: Какой сложности будет интеграция этого темйпелйта в мой код?

Comment: Мне кажется что в этом вопросе вы будете более компетентны, чем я :)

Comment: Ой, я так не думаю. Спасибо большое.